# Testing a hypothesis with significance level

Tags: statistics

Prove the hypothesis that the average content of containers of a particular lubricant is $10$ liters, if the contents of a random sample of $10$ containers are:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 10,2 & 9,7 & 10,1 & 10,3 & 10,1 \\\hline
 9,8 & 9,9 & 10,4 & 10,3 & 9,8 \\\hline
\end{array}

Use a significance level of $0.01$ and assume that content distribution is normal.

I started with the following:

In this case, use $t=\dfrac{\overline{x}-\mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}$, because I do not know anything about $\sigma$.

- $H_0: \mu= 10$.
- $H_1: \mu \neq 10$.
- $\alpha = 0,01$.
- How can I find the critical region?
- How I can decide if the hypothesis is correct?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test statistic is $\dfrac{\bar x - 10}{s/\sqrt{10}}$.  The "10" in the numerator comes from the null hypothesis; the "10" in the denominator is the sample size.

You need the number $c$ such that $\Pr(-c<T<c)=0.99$, when $T$ has a Student's t-distribution with $9$ degrees of freedom.  In this case the number of degrees of freedom is one less than the sample size because if you subtract $\bar x$ from each observed number, you get a set of numbers that must add up to $0$; hence if you know $9$ of them, you know all of them.  You can get that number $c$ from a table or from software.  You reject $H_0$ if $T>c$ or $T<-c$, or equivalently, if $|T|>c$.  That's the critical region.

The null hypothesis is *presumed* correct unless it is rejected, but you can never prove by such means that it is exactly correct.